# Add-on to open local folders in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have just started making an add-on with Firefox. This add-on is written in order to open a local folder outside FF. The folder is already opened by the browser. And in the context menu you will see an option to open the folder outside the browser (I use Win7).
This is the code that I used:

```js
var contextMenu = require("context-menu");

var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Open Local File",
    context: contextMenu.URLContext("file:///*"),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function() {'+
                        'openDir(document.URL);'+
                   '});',
});

function openDir(val)
{
    if (val == "")
    {
        alert("Directory not defined");
        return;
    }
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") == -1)
    {
        alert("Currently active folder links supported only for Mozilla Firefox web browser");
        return;
    }
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
    var localFile =
        Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

    var env =
        Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);

    var systemRoot = env.get("SystemRoot");
    if (systemRoot == "")
    {
        alert("Unable to retrieve SystemRoot environment variable");
    }

    localFile.initWithPath(systemRoot + "\\explorer.exe");
    var process =
        Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    process.init(localFile);
    process.run(false, Array(val), 1);
}
```

Now the problem is that when I save the add-on under http://builder.addons.mozilla.org/...  it cannot be compiled. Instead a red box shows up with the message "XPI not built". This is the log:

> GET https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/xpi/test/.../   404 NOT FOUND   236ms

What should I do?

---

The modified code:

```
    var contextMenu = require("context-menu");

    var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
        label: "Open Local File",
        contentScript: 'self.on("context", function(node)'+
                        '{'+
                        '  return node.ownerDocument.URL.indexOf("file:///") == 0;'+
                        '});'+
                        'self.on("click", function(node)' +
                        '{' +
                        '  self.postMessage(node.ownerDocument.URL);' +
                        '});',

        onMessage: function(url)
        {
          openDir(url);
        }

        }) ;

    function openDir(val)
    {
        var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
        var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                          .getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
        var uri = ioService.newURI(val, null, null);
        if (uri instanceof Ci.nsIFileURL && uri.file.isDirectory())
        {
          uri.file.QueryInterface(Ci.nsILocalFile).launch();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Add-on Builder web application is there to package up your code and create an extension - Firefox merely installs the extension once it is done. You have an issue with the Add-on Builder, not one with Firefox. I can only recommend you to [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=addons.mozilla.org&component=Add-on%20Builder).

Your code has numerous issues however:

- It seems that you want to show your context menu item on pages using the `file:///` URL scheme, not on links pointing to files. There is no predefined context for this, you will have to use the content script (see [Specifying Contexts > In Content Scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/context-menu.html). Something like:

```js
self.on("context", function(node)
{
  return node.ownerDocument.URL.indexOf("file:///") == 0;
});
```

- Function `openDir()` isn't defined in the content script, it is defined in your extension. This means that you have to send a message back to your extension with the URL (see last example in [Handling Menu Item Clicks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/context-menu.html)). Something like this:

```js
contentScript: 'self.on("context", ...);' +
               'self.on("click", function(node, data)' +
               '{' +
               '  self.postMessage(node.ownerDocument.URL);' +
               '});',
onMessage: function(url)
{
  openDir(url);
}
```

- Checking whether your code is running in Firefox is pointless - currently, the Add-on SDK only supports Firefox.
- You should not use the deprecated `PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege` method - your code is already running with highest privileges. You will need to [use chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html) however, extensions built with the Add-on SDK by default cannot access low-level functionality.
- You shouldn't run Windows Explorer directly, use [nsILocalFile.launch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications#Using_nsILocalFile.launch%28%29), for directories it will run Windows Explorer (or whatever action is defined in the operating system to open directories). Altogether the code in `openDir()` should look like this:

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var ioService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                  .getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
var uri = ioService.newURI(val, null, null);
if (uri instanceof Ci.nsIFileURL && uri.file.isDirectory())
  uri.file.QueryInterface(Ci.nsILocalFile).launch();
```

Documentation: [nsIIOService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIOService), [nsIFileURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFileURL).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have changed my add on to the code that I have just now appended to my post. but it seems that codes inside onMessage won't run.

Comment: Are you operating within exports.main of main.js ?

Comment: @BrettZamir: Doesn't matter. Some code that runs in an SDK-based extension.

Comment: @Wladimir: I'm just trying to address what limacina is saying on onMessage not running--just wondering if the code is in the right place.

Comment: @BrettZamir: I see. I doubt that he is still on that problem after more than a year however (probably didn't even get your message with it not being addressed to anybody).